# Estimate a linear trend in every row across multiple columns in order to project the next value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I have five columns of historic data which I'd like to find a linear trend across the columns in every row to project the next value in year 2021/22. The historic data is stored in a data frame as follows: -

| Index | 2016/17 | 2017/18 | 2018/19 | 2019/20 | 2020/21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 14.53 | 13.75 | 13.03 | 16.05 | 15.15 |
| 1 | 14.52 | 13.74 | 13.03 | 16.03 | 15.14 |
| 2 | 11.92 | 10.53 | 10.53 | void | void |
| 3 | 10.87 | 10.06 | 10.06 | 10.05 | 10.07 |
| 4 | 12.59 | 10.99 | 10.99 | 10.99 | 11.07 |
| 5 | 12.59 | 10.99 | 10.99 | 10.99 | 11.00 |
| 6 | 24.56 | 17.90 | 17.88 | 18.02 | 18.14 |
| 7 | 24.56 | 17.90 | 17.88 | 18.02 | 18.14 |
| 8 | 24.56 | 17.90 | 17.88 | 18.02 | 18.14 |
| 9 | 18.40 | 14.94 | 14.92 | 15.02 | 15.10 |
| 10 | 23.57 | 23.06 | 23.09 | 23.08 | 22.88 |

The projected output is then saved in the next column of the same dataframe.

| Index | 2016/17 | 2017/18 | 2018/19 | 2019/20 | 2020/21 | 2021/22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 14.53 | 13.75 | 13.03 | 16.05 | 15.15 | ? |
| 1 | 14.52 | 13.74 | 13.03 | 16.03 | 15.14 | ? |
| 2 | 11.92 | 10.53 | 10.53 | void | void | ? |
| 3 | 10.87 | 10.06 | 10.06 | 10.05 | 10.07 | ? |
| 4 | 12.59 | 10.99 | 10.99 | 10.99 | 11.07 | ? |
| 5 | 12.59 | 10.99 | 10.99 | 10.99 | 11.00 | ? |
| 6 | 24.56 | 17.90 | 17.88 | 18.02 | 18.14 | ? |
| 7 | 24.56 | 17.90 | 17.88 | 18.02 | 18.14 | ? |
| 8 | 24.56 | 17.90 | 17.88 | 18.02 | 18.14 | ? |
| 9 | 18.40 | 14.94 | 14.92 | 15.02 | 15.10 | ? |
| 10 | 23.57 | 23.06 | 23.09 | 23.08 | 22.88 | ? |

I have tried to use numpy.polyfit and scipy.linregress but both seems to give me problems due to having multiple columns instead of one columns. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of the code you tried for us as reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very basic example of how to take the five columns and predict the next one (the 6th) for the first row of the data, using scikit-learn.  `pip install scikit-learn` if you have not got it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

data = { '2016/17' : [14.53, 14.52],
'2017/18' : [13.75,13.74],
'2018/19' : [13.03,13.03],
'2019/20' : [16.05,16.03],
'2020/21' : [15.15,15.14]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

X = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]) # dummy x values for each of the columns you are going to use as input data
Y = df.iloc[0,:].values.reshape(-1, 1) # work on row 0
 
linear_regressor = LinearRegression()  # create object for the class
linear_regressor.fit(X, Y)  # perform linear regression

prediction = linear_regressor.predict(np.array([[6]]))
```

Now you will have to take this and get it to work row wise and put the answer into the column you want but the basic machinery is all there.

You will also have to deal with the interesting problems of void.  `imputation` is what you need but it will be problematic if too much data is missing.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I will explore how I could deal with the missing values using imputation.

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html here is the strategy, you can get a linear fit from two points but that doesn't really mean a lot (think of number of horses in 1900, 1910 and then forecast to 2020, not great).  So missing values will appoch the mean trend, so fit all the data and then insert the voids, then used the data above to get the forecast,  if you need more info ask away